# How to avoid delay in watch face rendering on samsung gear s2

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I have developed a watch face as a Tizen web application for my Samsung Gear S2.
Sometimes, when the watch face renders, for example reacting to a gesture, a previously cached image of the watch, showing the time from the last time it was running, is shown briefly, before the face showing the right time.
The watch face is setup to render each second, but I have added an event handler for `visibilitychange` as per the available examples:

```
// add eventListener to update the screen immediately when the device wakes up
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
    if (!document.hidden) {
        drawWatchContent(getDate());
    }
});
```

This annoying effect is not visible in the standard watch faces already available.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I have developed watch faces but haven't faced this kind of issue. You don't need to add visibilitychange event listener. Try using requestAnimationFrame which will optimize your watch face app.

Comment: On my Gear, also some native watch faces, e.g. the Bloomberg watch face, have this issue. Upon keypress, for a fraction of a second, I can see the previous position of the needles. This only seems to appear for watches with second-movement, not for those with sub-second movement. Are your watch faces web-applications or native?